# ASP.NET Core razor decimal in form value not valid

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, decimal

In my model:

```
[Range(1, 100)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
public decimal MyDecimal { get; set; }
```

In my cshtml file:

```
<input asp-for="MyModel.MyDecimal" class="form-control" step="0.01" type="number" value="0.00" />
```

It's not working: The value is not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my model:

```
public decimal MyDecimal { get; set; }
[Range(1, 100)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
public string MyDecimal_string { get; set; }
```

In my .cshtml file:

```
<input asp-for="MyDecimal_string" step="0.01" type="number" class="form-control" />
```

In my .CS file, I convert MyDecimal_string to decimal:

```
Mydecimal = decimal.Parse(MyDecimal_string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I am using .NET 5